# Check if next period starts from end of the previous period

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

I have several usage types. One is to prepare another is actual usage.

*Need to check if prepaid type start and end date in the previous period = (equal) start and end dates in next period for usage*

At the end of the period, I have prepared usage, according to the logic next period usage must match prepaid from the previous period. But some times I have cases where these two types don't match.
For example

```
  1  (128193    ,'2020-05-01',  '2020-05-31','prepaid'),
  2  (134145    ,'2020-06-01',  '2020-06-30','prepaid'),
  3  (134145    ,'2020-05-01',  '2020-05-30','usage'),
```

Example record number 3 should match record number 1 as it pre paid for that period, in this situation they  **usage** start and end date in period 134145  do not  mach  start and end date of **prepaid** in previous period 128193.

I need to find those cases.

I have created a script

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, startdate DATE, enddate DATE , u_type VARCHAR(255))

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 128193    ,'2020-05-01',  '2020-05-31','prepaid'),
         (134145    ,'2020-06-01',  '2020-06-30','prepaid'),
         (134145    ,'2020-05-01',  '2020-05-30','usage'),
         (141461    ,'2020-07-01',  '2020-07-31','prepaid'),
         (141461    ,'2020-06-01',  '2020-06-30','usage');
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS r ,
                        id ,
                        startdate ,
                        enddate,
                        u_type
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  c2.id ,
            c1.id, 
            c1.startdate,
            c1.enddate,
            c2.startdate,
            c2.enddate,
            c1.u_type,
            c2.u_type
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c2.r + 1 = c1.r AND  c2.u_type <> c1.u_type
    WHERE   DATEADD(d, 1, c2.enddate) <> c1.startdate
```

but it returns me the incorrect results.

It is one time run so I don't care about performance speed can use whatever will require as #tables CTEs, any ideas on how to fix it?

The prepaid record always goes for the future period.

Comment: I modified my answer. Plz, check if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, startdate DATE, enddate DATE , u_type VARCHAR(255))

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 128193    ,'2020-05-01',  '2020-05-31','prepaid'),
         (134145    ,'2020-06-01',  '2020-06-30','prepaid'),
         (134145    ,'2020-05-01',  '2020-05-30','usage'),
         (141461    ,'2020-07-01',  '2020-07-31','prepaid'),
         (141461    ,'2020-06-01',  '2020-06-30','usage');

WITH CTE_PERIOD_RANGE
     AS (SELECT ID, 
                STARTDATE, 
                ENDDATE, 
                U_TYPE, 
                LEAD(STARTDATE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY U_TYPE ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS NEXT_PERIOD_STARTDATE, 
                LEAD(ENDDATE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY U_TYPE ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS NEXT_PERIOD_ENDDATE
         FROM @t)
     SELECT ID, 
            STARTDATE, 
            ENDDATE, 
            U_TYPE
     FROM CTE_PERIOD_RANGE
     WHERE STARTDATE <> NEXT_PERIOD_STARTDATE OR 
           ENDDATE <> NEXT_PERIOD_ENDDATE AND 
           NEXT_PERIOD_STARTDATE IS NOT NULL; -- this filters out the last occurrence of each type, because this record has no following period
```

This will return:

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║   id   ║ startdate  ║  enddate   ║ u_type  ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ 128193 ║ 2020-05-01 ║ 2020-05-31 ║ prepaid ║
║ 134145 ║ 2020-06-01 ║ 2020-06-30 ║ prepaid ║
║ 134145 ║ 2020-05-01 ║ 2020-05-30 ║ usage   ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

See SQLFiddle: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c940bb16b8890972e9bf454205d5dfed)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it:

```
select
  p.id        as p_id,        u.id        as u_id,
  p.startdate as p_startdate, u.startdate as u_startdate,
  p.enddate   as p_enddate,   u.enddate   as u_enddate
from
  @t u
    inner join @t p
    on(
          p.u_type = 'prepaid'
      --
      and p.startdate <= u.enddate
      and p.enddate   >= u.startdate
    )          
where
    u.u_type = 'usage'
--
and (
     p.startdate <> u.startdate
  or p.enddate   <> u.enddate
)
```

We look for the `prepaid` that matches `usage` and then check their boundaries.

Comment: in your solution it does check only  inside of the current  period, but I need to check if the start and end date in previous prepaid = start and end in the next one . if not  return it

Comment: yes, prepaid in this mont  is prepaid for next  month